# Macro is converting numeric inputs to character. How to change it back to numeric?

Tags: macros, sas, character, numeric

I created a macro to split a dataset into a training and validation set. I noticed that the following %if statement was not evaluating correctly and recently learned that it's because the macro processor [does not make a distinction between character and numeric values as the rest of SAS does](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001071862.htm) (link to SAS documentation). I confirmed this by using the %eval function as shown below:

```
%else %if %eval(&split) <= 0 or %eval(&split) >= 1 %then %do;
    %put ERROR: The specified split of the data must be within the following range of real numbers (0,1].;
%end;
```

How can I fix this so that it will read my input for the macro variable "split" correctly as a decimal?

The following sample code can be used:

```
data test (drop=i);
do i=1 to 1000;
a=round(uniform(1)*4,.01);
b=round(uniform(1)*10,.01);
c=round(uniform(1)*7.5,.01);
if b<2 then d=1;
else d=0;
if i<500 then y=1;
else y=0;
output;
end;
stop;
run;

%macro train_valid(split=);
    %if &split =  %then %put ERROR: Missing an input. Check to make sure the macro variable has an input.;
    %else %if &split <= 0 or &split >= 1 %then %do;
        %put ERROR: The specified split of the data must be within the following range of real numbers (0,1].;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        proc surveyselect data=test samprate=&split seed=1000 out=Sample outall 
            method=srs noprint;
         run;
        data test_train; 
            set Sample; 
                where selected = 1;
        run; 
        data test_valid;
            set Sample; 
                where selected = 0;
        run;
    %end; 
%mend;
%train_valid(split=.75);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that by default SAS will evaluate conditions in %IF, %WHILE, etc using the `%EVAL()` function which can only handle integer comparisons. If you want to use floating point values or date literals then you need to explicitly use `%SYSEVALF()` to test the conditions.

```
%if %sysevalf(&split <= 0 or &split >= 1) %then %do;
```

Comment: I don't think I had understood how to use the %eval or %sysevalf function properly so this provided me with the solution and helped my understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting the %eval functions like so:

```
%eval(%eval(&split <= 0) or %eval(&split >= 1))
```